# Different PCA scores using prcomp and eigen in R

Tags: r, pca

I have data with 6 rows and 4 columns. My data are assigned to variable `data`.

I wanted to calculate PCA using `eigen` function in R:

```
S <- cov(data)
s.eigen <- eigen(S)
PCA <- data %*% s.eigen$vector
PCA
         [,1]      [,2]     [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 2.126205 -4.304502 3.865308 -2.190870
[2,] 1.909724 -3.670697 3.920960 -2.055483
[3,] 5.767312 -3.350387 4.069640 -2.175097
[4,] 4.781725 -3.338716 3.614298 -2.141244
[5,] 6.930657 -4.189078 3.887408 -2.075011
[6,] 6.054994 -4.212873 3.800341 -2.146195`
```

While, `prcomp` function returns the same rotation equal to eigen vectors, but final result of PCA is different:

```
            PC1        PC2          PC3         PC4
[1,] -2.4688982 -0.4601265 -0.005648564  0.06022000
[2,] -2.6853791  0.1736787 -0.061301164 -0.07516717
[3,]  1.1722093  0.4939885 -0.209980567  0.04444716
[4,]  0.1866223  0.5056591  0.245361119  0.01059379
[5,]  2.3355544 -0.3447025 -0.027749084 -0.05563912
[6,]  1.4598913 -0.3684974  0.059318259  0.01554534`
```

Why I get two different results for PCA using those two methods?

Answer (score 1):

You get different numbers because `prcomp` uses the centered data matrix for computing the scores, while in your calculations you used the original data matrix.

Here is how you can get the same result as `prcomp` using the eigenvalue approach:

```
t(t(data) - rowMeans(t(data))) %*% s.eigen$vectors
```

All this does is remove the column means from the data before rotation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your data. The same estimates of the principal components can be obtained from the eigendecomp of t(y)%*%y/(n-1), which is calculated by the cov-function.

```
y <- scale(matrix(rnorm(2*10),10,2)) #scale to have col. mean 0 and var 1
h <- prcomp(y)
h
h2 <- eigen(cov(y))
```

h2

The reported eigenvalues are then the squared sd.dev from the prcomp.